# How to pack ipa with signer for phonegap project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have create a phonegap project for ios. And I use phonegap command line to build `./cordova/build`. Then I use `xcrun` to generate an ipa, it fails.

This is my command line:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v ./build/page.app -o ~/Documents  
/ipas/page.ipa -sign "iPhone Distribution: [XXXXXXX]" -embed "XXX.mobileprovision"
```

And this is the error I got after execute the command.

```
Output directory: '/Users/longfei/Documents/ipas/page.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/n9/1pqsg0kj667d741s43cfnlw80000gn/T/kLf7Emmi2L'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp ./build/page.app /var/folders/n9/1pqsg0kj667d741s43cfnlw80000gn/T/kLf7Emmi2L/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv ./build/page.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [./build/page.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: i386
]
Codesign check fails : ./build/page.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: i386

Done checking the original app
Embedding '~/Dropbox/Works/xcode/zs/yunsite1/yunsite1.mobileprovision'
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/n9/1pqsg0kj667d741s43cfnlw80000gn/T/kLf7Emmi2L/Payload/page.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
+ /bin/cp -rp ~/Dropbox/Works/xcode/zs/yunsite1/yunsite1.mobileprovision /var/folders/n9/1pqsg0kj667d741s43cfnlw80000gn/T/kLf7Emmi2L/Payload/page.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/cp returned 1 : [cp: ~/Dropbox/Works/xcode/zs/yunsite1/yunsite1.mobileprovision: No such file or directory
]
error: Unable to copy '~/Dropbox/Works/xcode/zs/yunsite1/yunsite1.mobileprovision' to '/var/folders/n9/1pqsg0kj667d741s43cfnlw80000gn/T/kLf7Emmi2L/Payload/page.app/embedded.mobileprovision'
```

I'm a newbie for ios and phonegap. I have searched for a long time to get a solution, but failed. Hope you can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I never did it command line, but apparently there is a signing issue, in fact why don't you just import your project to xcode and set it up from there, it's far easier and faster to sign, package and debug

Answer (score 1):

Your command line looks OK (similar to mine).  Your problem is that you are signing a debug version of your phonegap build.  The error is there:

```
Codesign check fails : ./build/page.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: i386
```

The debug builds are i386 binaries so they run on the Mac, but the release builds are ARM binaries.  I don't use phonegap to do the build, but you need to build the Release version in order to sign. I do builds like so in my makefile:

```
ios-app:
        echo 'MAKE SURE YOU HAVE DONE security unlock-keychain login.keychain'
        cd $(ios_dir);xcodebuild -target $(app_name) -project $(app_name).xcodeproj -target $(app_name) -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=$(sign_identity) CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=`pwd`/build
        cd $(ios_dir);xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication $(ios_dir)/build/$(app_name).app -o $(ios_dir)/build/$(app_name).ipa -sign $(sign_identity) --embed $(cert_name)  -verbose
```

Bottom line is you need to sign the correct build of the package.